# Start activity from other activity in Kotlin. It crashes before loading xml

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, start-activity

In Kotlin, in loginButton.setOnClickListener function, the following codes can start ProfileActivity;

```
  val intent=Intent(this@LoginActivity, ProfileActivity::class.java)
                            startActivity(intent)
                            finish()
```

From the ProfileActivity, the following codes can start TestActivity;

```
 val intent=Intent(this@ProfileActivity, TestActivity::class.java)
                            startActivity(intent)
                            finish()
```

However, I want to start the TestActivity from the LoginActivity. So, I updated the codes by changing only the activity name and the codes are below:

```
 val intent=Intent(this@LoginActivity, TestActivity::class.java)
                            startActivity(intent)
                            finish()
```

But, the app crashes before loading activity_test.xml. Why ?

The class in the ProfileActivity.kt is;

```
class profileActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile)

    }
}
```

The class in the TestActivity.kt is;

```
class TestActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val QUANT = false
    private val LABEL_PATH = "labels.txt"
    private val INPUT_SIZE = 224 
 
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {  
            var strResultUri: String? = null
            strResultUri = savedInstanceState.getString(strResultUri)  
          } else { 

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_test) 

            textViewResult = findViewById(R.id.textViewResult)
            textViewResult?.setMovementMethod(ScrollingMovementMethod())
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Please add crash report too to your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: make sure that TestActivity  is registered in manifest .

Comment: It's very difficult to debug a crash without a stack trace. See [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](/q/23353173) for Android-specific advice, and [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](/q/3988788) for advice on what to do once you have the stack trace.  If you still need help, edit your question to include the **complete stack trace**, as well as **which line of your code** the stack trace points to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var strResultUri: String? = null
strResultUri = savedInstanceState.getString(strResultUri)
```

What exactly you do here? Passing null inside `savedInstanceState.getString()` method?

Also, what do you mean by changing only the name? You mean you just changed the context in the following code?

```
val intent=Intent(this@LoginActivity, TestActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
finish()
```

That code would work inside login activity for sure.

Also, is that a typing mistake. `profileActivity`. That's camel case (Not an accepted convention), and you call `ProfileActivity::class.java`. This shouldn't work. If it's just a typo, ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Most probabely your these lines cause issue:

```
var strResultUri: String? = null
strResultUri = savedInstanceState.getString(strResultUri)
```

Because you are passing `strResultUri` null value as parameter to `getString` method
It should be like this:

```
strResultUri = savedInstanceState.getString("yourKey")
```